# Ember Component Properties Pass by Name

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to pass a property into an Ember component. I don't know the name of the property at build time. The name is stored in a variable. How to I evaluate the variable before passing it into the component?

Let's say `element.selected = "form.username"` (I don't know this at build time). I want:

```
{{power-select options=element.options selected=element.selected}}
```

To become:

```
{{power-select options=element.options selected=form.username}}
```

I didn't write `power-select` so I can't change the way it behaves.

FYI I don't know the name of the property at build time because I receive an array of strings and for each element I make a input box (or similar). The values of the input box are stored in `form.THE_STRING_FROM_THE_ARRAY`. This isn't relevant other than saying there is no way to know the value of `element.selected` as build time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on ember 2.1.0+ you can use the [{{get}}](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_get) helper for this:

`{{power-select options=element.options selected=(get form computedPropertyThatReturnsTheDynamicName)}}`